# Управление циклом спомощью кнопки

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть у нас две кнопки в форме.
На одной(нет,не пики точенные) привязано создание массивов, заполнение массива данными,копирование и цикл сортировки пузырьком.
Как управлять циклом через другую кнопку?Пытался писать костыли и условия,но чувствую что за такой код,мне самому нужно выдать костыли.

---

```
private void StartSteps_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Form1.OpenFileName1 != null)
        {

            if (Form1.radioButton1.Checked == true)
            {
                Form1.Length1 = 10;
            }
            if (Form1.radioButton2.Checked == true)
            {
                Form1.Length1 = 10000;
            }
            int[] arrayOfnumbersAStep = new int[Form1.Length1];
            int[] arrayOfNumbersBStep = new int[Form1.Length1];
            int[] arrayOfNumbersCStep = new int[Form1.Length1];





            using (var stream = new FileStream(Form1.OpenFileName1, FileMode.Open))
            using (var reader = new BinaryReader(stream, Encoding.ASCII))
            {
                int i = 0;
                while (reader.PeekChar() != -1)
                {

                    if (i < arrayOfnumbersAStep.Length)
                    {
                        arrayOfnumbersAStep[i] = reader.ReadInt32();
                        i++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }


            Array.Copy(arrayOfnumbersAStep, arrayOfNumbersBStep, Form1.Length1);


            for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfNumbersBStep.Length; i++)
            {
                while (Bubbleclick)
                {
                    if (BubbleNext.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        iteratorBubble++;

                        for (IteratorBubble = 0; IteratorBubble < arrayOfNumbersBStep.Length - i - 1;)
                        {
                            firstValue.Text = arrayOfNumbersBStep[iteratorBubble].ToString();
                            secondValue.Text = arrayOfNumbersBStep[iteratorBubble + 1].ToString();
                            if (arrayOfNumbersBStep[IteratorBubble] > arrayOfNumbersBStep[IteratorBubble + 1])
                            {

                                int temp = arrayOfNumbersBStep[IteratorBubble];
                                arrayOfNumbersBStep[IteratorBubble] = arrayOfNumbersBStep[IteratorBubble + 1];
                                arrayOfNumbersBStep[IteratorBubble + 1] = temp;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    static bool bubbleclick = true;
    private void BubbleNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }
```

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под "Управлять циклом"?

Comment: @Seedorf есть в цикле переменная IteratorBubble ,какая указывает на определенную ячейку массива,вот нужно сделать так,что бы по нажатию кнопки BubbleNext ,значение вышеупомянутой переменной увеличивалось на 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Вашем случае можно просто в обработчике нажатия на кнопку прописать

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IteratorBubble++;
    }
```

а дальше осуществить метод, который вам необходим. Т. Е.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IteratorBubble++;
            method();
        }
```

где `method` - это метод, работающий с новым значением `IteratorBubble`

Comment: Захожу в сортировку и в итоге бесконечный цикл =\

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/dCcwF2GUmeeHZRupJ9YvSd

Comment: у вас булева переменная Bubleclick=true, поэтому цикл while (Bubbleclick) бесконечный